# Trying to make a combobox with drawMode as OwnerDrawFixed look like one that has a normal drawMode

Tags: c#, combobox

i want to have a combobox that has an event when a user hovers over an object so i had to make it have a drawMode as ownerDrawFixed. I tried to make it look like a regular combo box but cant get rid of the highlighting. so when the user clicks it, the object will have a highlighting but the text will still be black unlike a normal one when the text turns white. Also when i close the drop down its still highlighted unlike a normal comboboxlist. Ill include a few picture, its not that important but i would like to be able to do it. Here is the code and pictures:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        animals = new string[] { "hello", "good", "day" };
        comboBox1.DataSource = animals;
    }

    private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {

        float size = 0;
        System.Drawing.Font myFont;
        FontFamily family = null;

        switch (e.Index)
        {
            case 0:
                size = 8;
                family = new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif");
                break;
            case 1:
                size = 8;
                family = new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif");
                break;
            case 2:
                size = 8;
                family = new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif");
                break;
        }

        e.DrawBackground();

        myFont = new Font(family, size, FontStyle.Regular);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(animals[e.Index], myFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, Convert.ToInt32(e.Bounds.X), Convert.ToInt32(e.Bounds.Y));

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Heres what they look like

[image: pic]

Comment: Use the [event.State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawitemstate(v=vs.110).aspx) member to decide what color to use.

Comment: What are you accomplishing with that switch block?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sorry what is that? im not that good a programming

Comment: @LarsTech thats the spacing between items in the list

Comment: But every case block has the same code.  What's the point?  I'm not sure I understand what "spacing between items in the list" means.  Every item has the same height as set from the ItemHeight property.

Comment: this is just the code i got from someone showing me how to do it but he will using different fonts and colours etc, i just havnt taken it out yet and set them regularly

Comment: So what's the issue?  If you want the highlighted text color, just follow the example at the bottom of the link that @JohnnyMopp provided.

Comment: im trying but its confusing me

Comment: `using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected) ? Color.White : Color.Black )) e.Graphics.DrawString(animals[e.Index], myFont, brush ,..);`

Comment: @TaW where would that go taw?

Comment: 2nd line from the bottom, of course..!

Comment: hmm its still highlighting normal as before

Comment: You did __replace__ the old DrawString with the new one which uses the conditional brush, not just add it before, right?

Comment: ah yeh i commented the old one out before but forgot the brush but it works now thankyou very much